# Keeping door open to return to academia

Tags: tenure-track, industry, adjunct-faculty

I'm a lecturer in a good UK university with 10 years research experience (64 publications, £800k in grants, lead 3 teaching modules) and am at the end of 5 interview process for a pretty high up position in research at a charity. The role sounds great and is twice the salary, however I would not be contributing to research, rather I would be spearheading multiple programmes.

I would enjoy the role, but if 5-10 years down the line I missed the research and flexibility to chase what I saw fit with my expertise, will I have a written off a chance to return? Am I saying this is it? Are there any ways I could keep one for in the door just in case I might want to return to academia? Would this role be seen as an advantage to academia that I have not thought of?

Comment: Hard to say.  The nature of academia is changing.  For example, Uni. of Sydney appointed a Vice Chancellor without a PhD; apparently he has good connections to the government.  It is possible that the skills you've acquired in the industry/charity become valuable to academia and opens a door back into academia.   However, if you are competing based on say publications, you will probably lose out to some young researcher.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest hurdle you might face, unless you are proactive, is to get necessary letters of recommendation that are positively viewed by academics. Some of those might come from your employment, but it would be a mistake to lose contact with people in academia, such as your current colleagues. Your old university professors are probably less valuable at your stage, of course.

And, yes, some teaching on the side will help somewhat, but it isn't research that adjunct faculty do. Perhaps collaborating in research with your current colleagues would be better.

And, the nature of your employment might factor in, if you want to return to academia. You will probably be a bit behind in your field in a decade, unless what you do at the charity is closely related.

Industry research is usually very different from academic research, though it might not be so disparate at a charity. But if it is closely related, developing collaborations with academic researchers might be especially valuable for everyone. That will keep you relevant.

But, going back to an academic salary will be very difficult if you then have financial obligations that don't mesh well with a much lower income.

I'd spend some time thinking long term about your goals before you make a jump. And think about what the path will be along the way if you want to keep your options open.